# Plumbing - What is the min size of a Kitchen + Dishwaser drain in California? (1.5in or 2in)

Tags: plumbing, drain, california

**Code**: 2019 California Plumbing Code, Based on the 2018 Uniform Plumbing Code - https://up.codes/viewer/california/ca-plumbing-code-2019/chapter/7/sanitary-drainage#7

**Context:** I am moving the kitchen to a house extension on slab on grade. The existing bearing walls are 2x4s and I need a drainage Kitchen + Dishwasher line that runs along a bearing wall. The line will run about 8 ft with a vertical vent at 5ft. I cannot bore the studs of the load bearing wall.

**Design consideration:**

- Ideally, I would not want the PVC pipe to be in the kitchen cabinet, so I am thinking of building a non-load bearing (partition) wall adjacent to the load bearing wall. In other words, there is one layer of 2x4 which are bearing, and a second layer of 2x4 that is non-bearing, making the thickness of the wall (2) 2x4 about 7in.

**Questions**:

- What is the minimum drainage pipe I can use 1.5in or 2in? 2019 California Plumbing Code, Based on the 2018 Uniform Plumbing Code
- In that setup, does the 60% max bore apply to the non-load bearing wall, given that that the wall is there just for hiding the pipe and attaching the cabinets?
- Can I use hardware like a stud shoe to strengthen the stud to go higher than 60%?
- Is my only option to make the non-load bearing wall 2x6?
- It looks like I could notch 7/8 in in bearing and 1-3/8" in non-bearing, for a 2" drain to go in between. Any advice on this?

Comment: Have you tried asking the Local Authority Having Jurisdiction, that being the town inspector's office?  Their opinion is the one that matters.

Answer (score 1):

(Drain Fixture Units)

Kitten sink DFU : 2

Dishwasher DFU : 2

1-1/2" PVC max DFU : 3

**No.**

Sister the existing wall with 2x6s, use 2" PVC, and protection plates. Instead of 7" into the room, it's only 5.5"

Comment: I hope you like using holesaws....

Comment: You could just build the partition in front and butcher that however you want because it isn't load bearing *vertically*, but it will be horizontally if you hang cabinets off of it. However I stand by my answer because I've demoed stuff like this, going, *well this was some BS they did here....* - I stopped building walls with pipes in them with 2x4s long ago. Bathrooms get 2x6s on that wall. Which code requires for exterior these days anyway.

Comment: If you sister 2x6s with a 2x4 top plate do you need to take steps so the extra width of the new studs will help support the joists above?

Comment: On paper that's unquestionably a yes. Depending on the quality of all of the lumber and the nailing schedule though.... Off hand, if the hole for the pipe is less than 2' from the top or the bottom, then yes, because that's more like a notch with no length to develop into a sister.

Comment: What's a kitten sink? I've never seen one in 73 years. :-)

Comment: Thanks Mazura. What do you mean by horizontally taking the load of the cabinets?

Answer (score 0):

If the extra layer of wall is the full height of the kitchen it will support the upper cabinets so you have to build it accordingly, even if it isn't bearing the load of the upper floors.  You can't cut oversized holes if you use 2x4s.

It might be easier to move the bottom cabinets out from the wall 2 inches and run the pipe behind them.  You'll need a bit of framing to attach them to the wall, one or two custom side panels and a custom countertop 2 inches deeper than standard but that's often considered a luxury feature!

Comment: Hi Jay613, Thank you. How are about notching 7/8 in in bearing and 1-3/8" in non-bearing, for a 2" drain to go in between. Any advice on this?

Comment: I don't know notching rules but if you carefully measure the space behind the cabinet rear wall, notch the backs of the cabinet uprights suitably and channel the drywall suitably, you might not need to notch the studs or extend the counter.   That's all a bit of a hack job though that a contractor may not be willing to do.